# get the weekly distinct users count within two dates

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a log table `PRTL_UserAccessLog` which has columns `userID,datetime`. I need to get the weekly distinct counts of logged users between two custom dates like the following

```
from date:01 Dec 2017
todate:31 dec 2017
```

My week start date should be from sunday.
I have created the following query to get the result

```
    SET DATEFIRST 7
    SELECT DISTINCT 
       'week '+ CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, Datetime)AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS weeknumber,
   --I need to get the distinct count of users within this week as weekloggedcount
    FROM 
        dbo.PRTL_UserAccessLog
    WHERE
        Datetime > '2017-12-01' AND Datetime < '2017-12-31'
        AND usertypeid=1
    ORDER BY
       weeknumber
```

The result should be like this:

```
**Weeknumber**   **weeklogcount**
  Week48               10
  Week49               50
```

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh sql server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SET DATEFIRST 7
SELECT DISTINCT 
   'week '+ CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, Datetime)AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS weeknumber,
    COUNT(DISTINCT userID ) weeklogcount
FROM 
    dbo.PRTL_UserAccessLog
WHERE
    Datetime > '2017-12-01' AND Datetime < '2017-12-31'
    AND usertypeid=1
GROUP BY 'week '+ CAST(DATEPART(WEEK, Datetime)AS NVARCHAR(10))
ORDER BY weeknumber
```